# Can I clean up leaking LCD in cracked laptop screen?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, hp-laptop

My laptop screen has been cracked, and now there is a giant black and purple mark all over the screen. Is there any way for me to clean this up so that it does not obscure my view so much?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your laptop screen is unfixable.  You will have to order a replacement LCD panel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've ordered a replacement screen, I was just wondering if there was anything I could do while it's coming.

Comment: @velociraptor unfortunately no. You could attach an external monitor to the laptop and use that instead.

Comment: If I do that, is there a way for me to turn the laptop screen off so I can just look at the TV that I use?

Comment: If you are using Windos 7 and above win+p will give you some options.  you could always just close the lid, or cover it with a piece of paper

Comment: In screen resolution settings you can tell it to only use the external monitor, with the external monitor connected,right click on desktop and select "screen resolution"