# Is it still safe to use a laptop with a cracked LCD screen?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd

My daughter accidentally stepped on her laptop and cracked the screen. The superficial bit I'm not sure. Is it still safe to use? Will anything leak? This is the best picture I could get.

Comment: Can't see a picture, but yes, provided its not a touch screen with glass where she is going to touch it, it is safe to use.  There might or might not be some gunge which leaks out.  Its not toxic if it does.

Comment: Put cellophane tape over the crack to reduce change of getting cut.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I clean up leaking LCD in cracked laptop screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/1068765/can-i-clean-up-leaking-lcd-in-cracked-laptop-screen). In general it should be fine to technically “use.” But of course usability is limited by the extent of the damage. Can you connect the laptop to an external display and use it that way? The best permanent solution is to repair the laptop and get the LCD display replaced. Or, if it is a cheap laptop, just toss it and buy a new one.